# How to get element using document.getElementsByClassName when the class changes on click event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have this Javascript to get the elements by class names.
I want the `getLabels` function to be called on click of a div. The class changes occur in this click as well. I cannot get the element of which the class being changed in the click event, using the `document.getElementsByClassName`.

```
function getLabels(){
  var labels = document.getElementsByClassName("nf-checked-label");
  for(i=0; i<labels.length; i++){
    console.log(labels[i].innerText);
  }
}
var element = document.getElementById("nf-form-8-cont");
element.addEventListener("click",getLabels);
```

Comment: Then you need to attach the event using another class that not change when you click

Comment: you need something to identify the element(s). Id, class, name or any other type of css selection.